# Moved view items in left menu SWRevealViewController objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I use SWRevealViewController in my project on objective c. Sometimes when I slide left menu, then first item is moved. Only first item, I don't know why because it has the same margins like others.

Also, it's not tableview, it's just static views which created in storyboard.

Sometimes it's showed incorrect This

[image]

It's need to be like That

[image]
First item moved sometimes.

Any ideas? Thx for help ;)

Comment: cant get your ques please explain more specifically ..

Comment: @vaibhav question is fix uilabel padding postion. sometimes the first row text was not setting properly

Comment: @Vinodh that's right...

Comment: @lost.in.code `SWRevealViewController's` left menu configured with tableview and the label position you are getting wrong is placed inside the cell so just check the position and text alignment.. may solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use table view it will easy for you with optimize code. You can navigate each view in didSelect method of tableView.
Here is the code please try this.

```
arrMenuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"HOME",@"YOUR WORK", @"BOOKMARKS", @"GETSTARTED",@"SETTING", @"LOG OUT",nil];


#pragma mark - Table view delegate and data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return arrMenuItems.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellid = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:{

           HomeViewController *rootViewController = InstantiateVC(@"HomeViewController");

                UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
                [navController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];

                [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
                [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
            }
            break;
        }

        case 1:{
            YourWorkViewController *homeVC = InstantiateVC(@"YourWorkViewController");

            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
            [navController setViewControllers: @[homeVC] animated: YES];

            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];

            break;
        }

        case 2:{
            BookMarkViewController *writeToUsVC = InstantiateVC(@"BKBWriteToUsVC");

            writeToUsVC.isFromVCTag = WRITE_TO_US;

            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:writeToUsVC];
            [navController setViewControllers: @[writeToUsVC] animated: YES];

            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            GetStartedViewController *aboutUsVC = InstantiateVC(@"BKBAboutVC");


            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUsVC];
            [navController setViewControllers: @[aboutUsVC] animated: YES];

            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            SettingViewController *writeToUsVC = InstantiateVC(@"BKBWriteToUsVC");

            writeToUsVC.isFromVCTag = CONTACT_US;

            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:writeToUsVC];
            [navController setViewControllers: @[writeToUsVC] animated: YES];

            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
             LogOutViewController *writeToUsVC = InstantiateVC(@"BKBWriteToUsVC");

            writeToUsVC.isFromVCTag = CONTACT_US;

            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:writeToUsVC];
            [navController setViewControllers: @[writeToUsVC] animated: YES];

            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];



            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Please change your ViewController according your requirements.

Comment: question is padding not set for fist cell , but how the above code will fix it . I don't understand please explain

Comment: But also, very interesting how to set padding for the first element without rebuilding menu with tableview.

Comment: This may be auto layout problem.

Answer (score 0):

//modified code

//you can create everything with your own. It is very Simple way to use swreveal. I hope it will be helpful.

```
NSArray *menuItems;

menuItems = @[@"title",@"Edit Profile",@"Match",@"Add Event",@"Give",@"Events",@"Market place",@"Recognizes businesses",@"About",@"Termsnuse",@"changePassword",@"Logout"];


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
return [menuItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImageView*imgProfile=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 50, 50)];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = Black;
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

if (indexPath.row==0) {
    UILabel*lbl;
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 130)];

    UILabel*lblUserName;
    UIImageView*imgUser;
    imgUser=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 80, 80)];

    lblUserName=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 95, 200, 30)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    imgProfile.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

    NSUserDefaults*defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


     NSDictionary *dict = [defaults objectForKey:@"Ucountry"];



    NSString *strImage = [dict objectForKey:@"image"];

    if ([strImage isEqualToString:@""]) {

        NSLog(@"strImage====>%@",strImage);
//            strImage = [strImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
//            NSURL *imageURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:strImage];
//            [imgUser sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user"]];
    }else{
        strImage = [strImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        NSURL *imageURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:strImage];
        [imgUser sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user"]];
    }







    imgUser.layer.cornerRadius=40;
    imgUser.clipsToBounds=YES;
    imgUser.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
    imgUser.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    //imgUser.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome_rabecca"];


    NSString *strFullName =[dict objectForKey:@"firstName"];
    lblUserName.text=strFullName;
    lblUserName.textColor=White;
    lblUserName.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lblUserName.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:14];
    lblUserName.backgroundColor=Black;

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:imgUser];
    [cell addSubview:lblUserName];

}
else if (indexPath.row==1)

{
    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Edit Profile";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];
}
else if (indexPath.row==2)

{
    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Match a Friend";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"match"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];

}
else if (indexPath.row==3)

{
    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Post Charity Events";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"addevent"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];

}

else if (indexPath.row==4)
{

    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Give to Causes";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"give"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];

} else if (indexPath.row==5)
{

    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Events";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"event"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];


} else if (indexPath.row==6) {

    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Market Place";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"market"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];


}
else if (indexPath.row==7) {

    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Promote Your Business";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"market"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];


}
else if (indexPath.row==8) {

    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"About";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"about"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];

}


else if (indexPath.row==9) {

    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Terms of Use";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"term"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];

}
else if (indexPath.row==10){
    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Change Password";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"changePassword"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];


} else if (indexPath.row==11){
    UILabel*lbl;
    UILabel*lblLine;
    UILabel*lbln;
    UIImageView*img;
    img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 12, 20, 20)];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    lbln=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 0, 320, 44)];

    lblLine=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 39, 320, 1)];
    lblLine.backgroundColor=bgColor;
    lbl.backgroundColor=Black;
    lbl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    lbl.layer.borderColor=bgColor.CGColor;
    lbln.text=@"Logout";
    lbln.textColor=White;
    lbln.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Kiro" size:18];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout"];

    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [cell addSubview:lbln];
    [cell addSubview:img];
    [cell addSubview:lblLine];
}
/*

 */
// cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

   return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row==0) {
    return 130;
}else if (indexPath.row==13)
{
   return 70;
}else{
    return 40;
}

}
```